# On clicking prev and next buttons page refreshes in Bx-slider

Tags: bxslider, page-refresh

I used and using Bxslider on my many websites but never faced this issue before, I know bxsliders prev and next buttons takes the page link in href but taking in that way in this site http://kmvgroup.com/test1/constructions-project-gallery/  on click refreshing the page.

I used this bx slider in many site before here is one such site http://www.reddogdiner.com/ the slider used is bx-slider but this works fine on clicking next and previous buttons the slider goes to next slide instead of page refresh/reload.

I cannot understand why this is happening in my above site. I used normal bx code wrapped my content in this way

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
<div class="background" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 335px;">
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 33%;">[awesome-gallery id=1435]</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 33%; width: 33%;">[awesome-gallery id=1438]</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 66%; width: 33%;">[awesome-gallery id=1440]</div>
</div>
<div class="background" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 335px;">
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 33%;">[awesome-gallery id=1485]</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 33%; width: 33%;">[awesome-gallery id=1493]</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 66%; width: 33%;">[awesome-gallery id=1502]</div>
</div></li>
    <li>
<div class="background" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 335px;">
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 33%;">[awesome-gallery id=1435]</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 33%; width: 33%;">[awesome-gallery id=1438]</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 66%; width: 33%;">[awesome-gallery id=1440]</div>
</div>
<div class="background" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 335px;">
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 33%;">[awesome-gallery id=1485]</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 33%; width: 33%;">[awesome-gallery id=1493]</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 66%; width: 33%;">[awesome-gallery id=1502]</div>
</div></li>
</ul>
```

included related files and called bxslider jquery function the only problem is with page refresh please someone help me regarding this,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. So i used Mozilla's devtools, and i saw that there're several events on buttons. So i clean some needless events and it's gone.